# How to obtain the GitLab runner ID from the authentication_token?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-api

When I register a runner, I can list my runner details with:

```
# gitlab-runner list
Runtime platform               arch=amd64 os=linux pid=103997 revision=7a6612da version=13.12.0
Listing configured runners     ConfigFile=/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml
runner-myproject               Executor=docker Token=xxx URL=https://gitlab.example.com
```

So I have the authentication_token in that response (also available in my config.toml).
From that runner token, how can I determine the runner ID?

I would like a cron that checks if the runner is busy and if not, it deregisters the runner from the autoscaling group:

1. Checks if the runner has active jobs
2. Pause the runner if there are 0 active jobs (would probably ensure that it has been idle for a while).
3. Deregister the runner from GitLab.
4. Deregister the runner instance from the AWS autoscaling group.

However, the API only works with the runner ID and all I know about the runner is the Token.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have a similar need - trying to pause the runner if the EC2 instance is scaling in, but I need the runner's ID to make the API call to Gitlab.

Comment: No, I changed companies and haven't used GitLab since then.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this information from the API.

First, you can get all the runners for an instance or for a specific project (depending on your requirements) like so:

```sh
# For the instance:
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/runners/all"

# For a specific project id
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/:project_id:/runners"
```

The result will look something like:

```json
[
    {
        "active": true,
        "description": "test-2-20150125",
        "id": 8,
        "ip_address": "127.0.0.1",
        "is_shared": false,
        "runner_type": "project_type",
        "name": null,
        "online": false,
        "status": "offline"
    },
    {
        "active": true,
        "description": "development_runner",
        "id": 5,
        "ip_address": "127.0.0.1",
        "is_shared": true,
        "runner_type": "instance_type",
        "name": null,
        "online": true,
        "status": "paused"
    }
]
```

You can then loop through the runners, grab the `id`, and get all jobs for that runner with the other API call you found already.
[Here's the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/runners.html#list-all-runners) for more details and options for this API:

Comment: how can I correlate the ID you have from that response to the runner token? Basically need to get the ID of the runner from within the runner and that is where I am at a lost.

Comment: If you need the ID from inside a running Pipeline Job, you can use the `CI_RUNNER_ID` [Predefined Variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved this problem for myself, it's a little convoluted but works:

I scraped the `gitlab-runner` logs to find the ID of the latest job, then called the Gitlab `jobs` API to get info about that job, which includes the runner's id:

```bash
JOB_ID=$(tail -1 /var/log/gitlab-runner.log | jq -c 'select( .job != null ) | .job')
RUNNER_ID=$(curl http://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/$PROJECT_ID/jobs/$JOB_ID | \
   jq -c '.runner.id')
```

This will only work if:

1. the runner's host has run at least one job
2. you know the `PROJECT_ID`

In my case, it was OK to fail if the runner had never done a job, and each runner only runs jobs for one project. Hopefully this helps someone!